# Ruby: why this WHEN-statement doesn't work with two conditions?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, operators

I have a `case` in my Ruby code that basically tries to match string in a couple of ways and do different things to it accordingly, kind of like that:

```
case inst
when Rx_inst1
  (some function)
when Rx_inst2
  (some other function)
end
```

This works beautifully (I'm not posting the RegEx as it's very, very long and works well). However, when I tried implementing the following modification, so that even when the RegEx matches a string, the condition is not executed if it contains a substring:

```
case inst
when Rx_inst1
  (some function)
when Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./
  (some other function)
end
```

it `Rx_inst2` stopped matching `inst` when it was equal `Nm. Friese = Fryzyjczyk, koń fryzyjski` or any other kind of string it matched before.

I got the exact same result with `&& /dom\./` and `&& inst.include?('dom.')` which, according to other answers, are proper syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case inst
when Rx_inst1
  (some function)
when Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./
  (some other function)
end
```

case translates into bunch of if/elsif/else statements with .=== operator
so your code is equvalent to

```
if Rx_inst1 === inst
  (some function)
elsif (Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./) === inst
  (some other function)
end
```

and `(Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./) === inst` works like this:

1. `(Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./)` part evaluates to `!/dom\./` (Rx_inst2 is a RegEx and is not nil or false)
2. `!/dom\./ === inst` gives you the result

so
`when Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./` matches whenever `!/dom\./ === inst` matches

Comment: oh, so RegEx returning a nil is does not itself equal nil? Interesting. Why did my final solution, the one in my answer, work then? Is it because it first evaluates the expression as true/false and then tries matching RegEx as match or null-match?

Comment: @MrVocabulary no, it's because `!inst.include?('dom.')` either returns `true` or `false`. If `false`, all this `&&` expression returns `false` and `false === inst` also returns `false` (unless `inst` is `false` itself, but it can't happen here, because it would crash earlier). If `true`, `&&` expression returns the second operand, which is `Rx_inst2` and the `Rx_inst2 === inst` comparison takes place, which returns correct result.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious, `Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./` returns (due to short circuit evaluation) value of the second operand, which is `!/dom\/` (provided `Rx_inst2` is indeed a `Regexp` and thus truthy). You probably need to modify this regexp in `Rx_inst2`, there's no short answer.

Alternatively, you could change all this `case` expression a little bit, like this:

```
case
when inst =~ Rx_inst1
  # (some function)
when inst =~ Rx_inst2 && !(inst =~ /dom\./)
  # (some other function)
end
```

but it isn't expecially elegant form, in my opinion.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that why short circuit evaluation is obvious here?

Comment: Well, treat `Rx_inst2 && !/dom\./` as a separate expression (which it is). How does it evaluate?

BTW in Ruby, all these operators: `&&, ||, and, or` use short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: both return `true` separately, so as a whole shouldn't it be `true` when both elements are `true`?

Comment: No, first of all, in Ruby binary logical operators don't return only boolean values. 
I edited my answer to provide a little bit hacky alternative way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: I've just tried it your way and the result is the same as before. I can guarantee my RegEx was matching fine until I tried adding a second condition.

Comment: @MrVocabulary I don't doubt it, this doesn't seem to be a problem in your case. So what happened after you applied my little bit hacky way?

Comment: it just didn't match those strings I wanted it to match, just as in any permutation I tried before.

Comment: @MrVocabulary oh, sorry, I made a mistake in my hacky solution code, fixed it, now it should work as you want and is a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

@Darigazz has nicely explained how `case` works and why your code is faulty. Here are a couple ways you might write your case statement.

**#1**

```
case inst
when Rx_inst1
  m1  
when Rx_inst2
  m2 if inst.match? /dom\./
end
```

`nil` is returned if `inst.match? /dom\./ #=> false` in `m2 if inst.match? /dom\./`. Depending on requirements, `if` might be replaced by `unless`.

**#2**

```
case inst
when Rx_inst1
  m1  
when /(?=.*dom\.)#{Rx_inst2}/
  m2
end
```

where `(?=.*dom\.)` is a *positive lookahead*. For example,

```
Rx_inst2 = /Bubba|Trixie/
/(?=.*dom\.)#{Rx_inst2}/
   #=> /(?=.*dom\.)(?-mix:Bubba|Trixie)/
```

Depending on requirements, `(?=.*dom\.)` might be replaced by the *negative lookahead* `(?!.*dom\.)`.

Comment: Thanks for those. I'm trying to learn producing more compact code, hence avoid nesting too many ifs. Plus the lookahead won't work as the substring is inside the matched string, which I haven't stated explicitly, but was my intention all along ;-)

Comment: Please elaborate the last sentence of your comment (and correct "started").

Comment: Stated*. I first check if the string conforms to my regex - it's a big one, and the unwanted "dom." can be almost anywhere. Inserting lookahead/lookbehinds would be ungainly and straining CPU a lot. Using include inserted of modifying the  regex makes much more sense in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turned out I made it work like that:

`when (!inst.include?('dom.') and Rx_inst2)`

I still don't understand why I had to do all these three following things, though:

1. change the order of operations
2. bracket the entire expression
3. call first one explicitly, and the second one implicitly

Comment: Don't use `and`, it's confusing, use `&&` instead. Plus it's even more hacky than my way (it relies on `=== false` comparison under the hood), so if you indeed apply this solution, I somewhat sympathize with the developer who might see this code later.

Comment: @Marek Lipka to me it's more readable. Apart from precedence in operations, like for `!` and `not`, does it really change anything?

Comment: @Marek Lipka probably no other person will see that code, plus it's dealing with a narrow scope of cases. I'll keep it unless shows me a one-liner to do the same thing with better practice involved. Thanks for the suggestions, though, lead me to some interesting lecture about operators :)